# Can I use domain name instead of IP to connect SOCKS5 proxy server?

Tags: ip, domain-name, socks-proxy, socks, socks5

I have domain name with correct A- and AAAA-records and my personal SOCKS5 Dante Server. Via IP all is okay, but when I try to connect via domain it's failed. So is it real to set up or impossible? Clients can resolve DNS of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of incorrect IPv6 settings on server-side. So client tried by default connect to IPv6 version but server not responded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use send domain name to socks5 server.

you can setup dante socks client where you need to edit /etc/socks.conf

Set "resolveprotocol" to "fake" in the client configuration file. then client will start passing the domain name to socks server directly.